# Password manager-auto id and password in java

Tags: java, android

HI i am developing password manager application in android......How can i generate auto user id and password for particular websites account in android for password manger application?    IN .details.... 
first i created database which is contain id,websites names,user id and password
so when i enter websites names in edit text it ll save to database then how can i created auto id and password for single website name in database

so if any one  know source code for this above statement let me know..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can base the userID and password on the unique AndroidID ? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).

Comment: no i mean auto randomly generate user id  and password  for accounts in database..